# PyTorch and EasyOCR: Avoid string separation

Tags: python, pytorch, ocr

I just started with OCR and looking for a solution for the following problem.

I noticed that in some cases PyTorch detects two separate strings instead of a single string. This is indicated with the green rectangles in the screenshot. Is it possible to change some settings in order to avoid this?

[image]

Any suggestion, links and explanations are very welcome. As well as the introduction to new vocabulary in case my question is not well phrased.

Code:

```
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['de'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext(file) # file is a jpg
```

Comment: PyTorch doesn't detect anything. Which code are you using to do the detection?

Comment: @Berriel, I just included the code.

Comment: @KJ and how do I have to perform the training?

Comment: @KJ, I have about 100 images and would seriously like to avoid any editing. Would it be possible to define something, that findings in very close proximity are automatically combined?

Comment: @peter always try to provide a [mre], at least the import statements to avoid people making wrong assumptions

Comment: @Berriel, I included all import statements of the script, some are not directly relevant though. However I can't share the complete image.

Comment: @KJ thank you very much for clarifying. I think that points me in the right direction. To elaborate a bit further. The jpgs are derived from multipage pdf files. The screenshot above shows dates which are zero-padded and always follow the same format which is 'day.month'. So far I did not specify anything for OCR. I just use the above code with the result shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @KJ `width_ths` is what I was looking for!